# Floating an image to the left with text to its bottom right

Tags: html, css

[image: what I have so far]
I'd like to make my text align from the bottom of the img.

Like below :

[image: what i'd like to do]

Do somebody knows how to make that trick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexblox on the wrapping element, and you can then justify/align the items as needed.

```
<div style="display:flex;align-items:end;">
  <div style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:gray">Replace this div with image tag</div>
  <span>Text text text</span>
</div>
```

[Click here to see codepen example](https://codepen.io/codepenkate/pen/oNdyOpw).